'DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique' when importing contracts from different files
If I write the three contracts that drive me to this error in the same file, everything works fine. It happens both in Remix and VSC. It looks like this:
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract A{
uint public a;

constructor (uint _a){
  a = _a;
}

}

abstract contract B is A{
  uint public b = 10;
}

contract C is B{
  uint public c;
  
  constructor(uint _a, uint _c) A(_a){
    c = _c;
  }
}

The issue comes when I have them separated into different files and import one into another like this:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.25;

contract A{
uint public a;

constructor (uint _a){
  a = _a;
}

}

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.25;

import {A} from "./A.sol";

abstract contract B is A{
  uint public b = 10;
}

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.25;

import {B} from "./B.sol";

contract C is B{
  uint public c;
  
  constructor(uint _a, uint _c) A(_a){
    c = _c;
  }
}

This is the error I receive:
from solidity:
DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
 --> contracts/C.sol:9:33:
  |
9 |   constructor(uint _a, uint _c) A(_a){
  |                                 ^


Use this line your C contract import {A} from "./A.sol";
